# If statement to compare a specific letter or phrase of a url to a set string

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to make an if statement where it will compare a URL that is stored in a JSON file to a set string such as tes or al or even a letter. Its a JSON file with products and their corresponding shop and I have a script where it will run through the JSON file but I want to have it showing what shop it is.
Something like

```
if(the first few letters === https://www.goo) {
  google
} else if(the first few letter === https://yah) {
  yahoo
}
```

Is there a way for this?

Below is my entire javascript

```
const endpoint = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/valeriu7474/4df04fafd994c2f778847a3e94451b44/raw/d288ddbc9cbc8bbcf89a10f2a8ead9eecb4962f6/allcurrentshops";



const name = [];
fetch(endpoint).then(blob => blob.json())
.then(data => name.push(...data));




    function findMatches(wordToMatch, name) {
        return name.filter(place => {
            //we need to figure out if the name match
            const regEx = new RegExp(wordToMatch, 'gi');

            return place.name.match(regEx);

        });
    }

function displayMatches() {
  const searchText = document.querySelector('.search').value;
  const matchArray = findMatches(searchText, name);


//You can set your total initials value to assume in
const LENGTH_TO_CONSIDER = 16
const initials = (website, size) => website.substring(0,size);

//Set key name as URL name with above defined length
const shop_names = {
'https://www.lidl' : 'Centra',
'https://shop.sup' : 'SuperValu'
}

let shop = shop_names[initials(url, LENGTH_TO_CONSIDER)]




  const html = matchArray.map(place => {
    const regex = new RegExp(searchText);
    const nameName = place.name.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${searchText}</span>`);

    return `
        <a href="${place.url}" target="_blank">
            <li>
                <span class="name">${nameName} <br> ${(place.price)} <br> ${(place.shop)} </span> 
                <img src="${place.imgurl}" alt="Drink Image" height="87.5" width="100">
            </li>
        </a>
    `;
  }).join('') || 'No Searches Found';
  suggestions.innerHTML = html;
};




const suggestions = document.querySelector('.suggestions');

const searchBtn = document.querySelector('.btn-search');
searchBtn.addEventListener('click', displayMatches);


document.getElementById('search').onkeydown = function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        displayMatches();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this

```
//You can set your total initials value to assume in
const LENGTH_TO_CONSIDER = 15
const initials = (website, size) => website.substring(0,size);

//Set key name as URL name with above defined length
const shop_names = {
'https://www.goo' : 'google',
'https://yaho': 'yahoo'
....
}
```

When you have URL, you can find shop name as

`let shop = shop_names[initials(url, LENGTH_TO_CONSIDER)]`

Comment: I have added the entire javascript

Comment: Given that `endpoint` what was the data you wanted to extract ?

Comment: Seems like you need combination of  [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`String.substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) and implement logic to find best matching.